# Escape dollar sign in Configuration.ini File for powershell install

Tags: powershell, escaping

Consider a powershell script to install SQL Server. This script is based on what [Colin's ALM Corner](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/install-and-configure-sql-server-using-powershell-dsc) has presented. It's been edited runs for my needs and all works perfectly until it hits the part in the Configuration.ini that contains an account which uses a password with a `$` in it.

`AGTSVCACCOUNT="IHA\.service-sqlbts-dev"
AGTSVCPASSWORD='Pa$$word'`

Notice that the Configuration.ini password does have single quotes around it I've also tried escaping the `$` with a backtick to no avail as well.

This same password DOES work when the password is supplied VIA command line args in the .ps1 script (just like how Colin does it).

`Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=c:\temp\ConfigurationFile.ini /SQLSVCPASSWORD=P2ssw0rd /AGTSVCPASSWORD='Pa$$word'`

But that same method when moved the Configuration.ini does not work.

Is there any way to escape the passwords when they are contained in a **Configuration.ini** (as opposed to providing password on $cmd) or do I need to stick with command-line args (or new passwords).

Comment: Would it perhaps make more sense to escape the single quotes on the $cmd line `/AGTSVCPASSWORD=(backtick)'$AGTSVCPASSWORD(backtick)'`

Comment: @TreyNuckolls It's not the single quotes that are causing the problem. It's the fact that the password contains a `$` which is a special character in powershell. The single quotes are supposed to escape the dollar sign, but they only do so when used in the command line.

Comment: In my testing, the method I'm suggesting does produce a string output from powershell that is equivalent to the line that you said works from the command line despite the special charecters.  It does not format well in the comments so I'll go ahead and add an answer to better demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Password='Pa$$word'
$cmd = "$setupDriveLetter\Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=c:\temp\ConfigurationFile.ini /SQLSVCPASSWORD=P2ssw0rd /AGTSVCPASSWORD=`'$Password`' /SAPWD=P2ssw0rd"
$cmd
```

Produces a string value for $cmd that is...

```
\Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=c:\temp\ConfigurationFile.ini /SQLSVCPASSWORD=P2ssw0rd /AGTSVCPASSWORD='Pa$$word' /SAPWD=P2ssw0rd
```

Using this method, when I set $cmd to be an argument of an, albeit simpler, module like set-content, the results appear to be the same as the resultant string value from above.

Comment: I appreciate the input however, I CAN get it to escape in the $cmd. Where it's not escaping is when I supply the password inside the Configuration.ini. I want to supply the passwords inside the .ini rather than on the command line so I can just do: `\Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=c:\temp\ConfigurationFile.ini` and it works for all passwords except those containing the `$`

Comment: Ah.  So you are looking to build the INI with this password populated within that file.  So this is less of a powershell issue and more of an issue with the build of the INI file for the setup executable.  The only thing I can say is that the password looks like it should be enclosed in in quotes.  Beyond that, if it works with other passwords you should likely go with that as I don't see any documentation regarding escapes in INI files as they are not completely standardized.